# How to io_control of boost library socket with customized command

Tags: boost-asio, ioctl

I' trying to make an identical function to "ioctl" in c++ style using boost library.

Here is my "c" style code:

```
int sockfd;
char * id;
struct iwreq wreq;

memset(&wreq, 0, sizeof(struct iwreq));
sprintf(wreq.ifr_name, IW_INTERFACE);

if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open socket \n");
    fprintf(stderr, "errno = %d \n", errno);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error description is : %s\n",strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
printf("Socket opened successfully \n");


id = malloc(IW_ESSID_MAX_SIZE+1);
wreq.u.essid.pointer = id;
if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIWESSID, &wreq)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Get ESSID ioctl failed \n");
    fprintf(stderr, "errno = %d \n", errno);
    fprintf(stderr, "Error description : %s\n",strerror(errno));
    exit(2);
}
printf("IOCTL Successfull\n");
printf("ESSID is %s\n", wreq.u.essid.pointer);
```

I found some relevant example, but I'm not clear how to use it correctly. [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/io_control/overload2.html)

Main function:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service);
struct iwreq wreq
memset(&wreq, 0, sizeof(struct iwreq));
sprintf(wreq.ifr_name, IW_INTERFACE);
id = malloc(IW_ESSID_MAX_SIZE+1);
wreq.u.essid.pointer = id;

boost::asio::detail::io_control::myCommand command;
command.set(&wreq);
boost::system::error_code ec;
socket.io_control(command, ec);
if (ec)
{
  // An error occurred.
}
```

Custom command:

```
#include <boost/asio/detail/config.hpp>
#include <cstddef>
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detail/socket_types.hpp>

#include <boost/asio/detail/push_options.hpp>

namespace boost {
namespace asio {
namespace detail {
namespace io_control {

// I/O control command for getting number of bytes available.
class myCommand
{
public:
  // Default constructor.
  myCommand()
    : value_(0)
  {
  }


  // Get the name of the IO control command.
  int name() const
  {
    return static_cast<int>(SIOCGIWESSID);
  }

  // Set the value of the I/O control command.
  void set(struct iwreq* value)
  {
    value_ = static_cast<detail::ioctl_arg_type>(value);
  }

  // Get the current value of the I/O control command.
  std::size_t get() const
  {
    return static_cast<struct iwreq*>(value_);
  }

  // Get the address of the command data.
  detail::ioctl_arg_type* data()
  {
    return &value_;
  }

  // Get the address of the command data.
  const detail::ioctl_arg_type* data() const
  {
    return &value_;
  }

private:
  detail::ioctl_arg_type value_;
};

} // namespace io_control
} // namespace detail
} // namespace asio
} // namespace boost
```

However, the code does not work. 
If you have any example code or solution, please let me know. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Asio, an [IoControlCommand](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/IoControlCommand.html) class provides support for a specific ioctl command. Asio itself includes one such class, `bytes_readable`, which handles the `FIONREAD` command. (It is the [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/asio/detail/io_control.hpp) mentioned in the question.)

The argument to `FIONREAD` is a pointer to an integer<sup>1</sup>, as shown here in C-style code:

```
int fd, value, ret;
/* ... */
ret = ioctl(fd, FIONREAD, &value);
```

Because of this, Asio's `bytes_readable` class has a private member variable that holds an integer, and `data()` returns a pointer to it.

ㅤ

The argument to `SIOCGIWESSID`, however, is a pointer to an instance of `struct iwreq`. The custom IoControlCommand class should store and initialize that instance, and `data()` should return a pointer to it:

```
#include <linux/wireless.h>
#include <string>

class myCommand
{
public:
  // Construct with a specific command value.
  myCommand(std::string interface)
    : wreq_(), essid_()
  {
    interface.copy(wreq_.ifr_name, sizeof(wreq_.ifr_name));
    wreq_.u.essid.pointer = essid_;
    wreq_.u.essid.length = sizeof(essid_);
  }

  // Get the name of the IO control command.
  int name() const
  {
    return static_cast<int>(SIOCGIWESSID);
  }

  // Get the current value of the I/O control command.
  std::string essid() const
  {
    return essid_;
  }

  // Get the address of the command data.
  void* data()
  {
    return &wreq_;
  }

  // Get the address of the command data.
  const void* data() const
  {
    return &wreq_;
  }

private:
  struct iwreq wreq_;
  char essid_[IW_ESSID_MAX_SIZE + 1];
};
```

To use this class:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_service);

myCommand cmd(IW_INTERFACE);

boost::system::error_code ec;
socket.io_control(cmd, ec);
if (ec)
{
  // An error occurred.
}

std::string essid = cmd.essid();
std::cout << "ESSID is " << essid << std::endl;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The exact integer type is platform-specific: it is `int` for [Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html#:%7E:text=FIONREAD), but `unsigned long` for [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/winsock-ioctls#fionread). For this reason `value_` is defined using a type alias, `boost::asio::detail::ioctl_arg_type`.